# Unable to Configure MQTT Client ID using Adafruit MQTT Library

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, adafruit

I am utilizing the MQTT library that Adafruit has created, located [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MQTT_Library), and the library itself works wonderfully - however I am finding myself unable to edit the Client ID or configure the PINGRESP. The code that I am currently using can be seen below -

```
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, "10.116.10.191", 1883);
```

When the client connects to the MQTT Broker the client ID turns into a random string of letters, numbers, and symbols, as seen below -

```
1534023607: Client ]7llG5K6J4=^tPHJHqgTUFc<Ep^m3vJ`4vSL2oB<cO[^_chw[GBp]v3smagpOqWS has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.
1534023608: New connection from 10.116.7.21 on port 1883.
1534023608: New client connected from 10.116.7.21 as ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu (c1, k300).
1534023608: Sending CONNACK to ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu (0)
1534023608: Received SUBSCRIBE from ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu
1534023608:     quantity (QoS 0)
1534023608: ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu 0 quantity
1534023608: Sending SUBACK to ^k_aQq];7xigbIUD`htDex>IPfAoNX:4JiUkR9vY9WG[`m`GL[KqZJAk7RaEkkIu
```

After a duration of time has passed the client exceeds the time out and disconnects.. Any advice on overcoming this obstacle would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use screenshots for text. Just include the text in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the library the implication is that you should pass the clientid in as an argument to the client constructor after the broker port.

```
 Adafruit_MQTT_Client(Client *client, const char *server, uint16_t port,
   const char *cid, const char *user, const char *pass):
```

From [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MQTT_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h#L38)

e.g.

```
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, "10.116.10.191", 1883, "clientfoo");
```

Also see this blog [post](https://io.adafruit.com/blog/notebook/2017/10/24/mqtt-clients-topic/#using-the-clients-topic) from adafruit

Comment: This was the result of adding the clientID, ("Rear-Controller"), after the MQTT Broker port # -

New client connected from 10.116.7.21 as GFONMktFXFSG1rARE@JWCRv@P^XwLifdo<rCg]YFs4Ndf_>2_XIsjFsAtS08Cf\: (c1, k300, uRear-Controller).